# Cat file do some operation append from file output to first file

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I'm trying to achieve the folowing:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  if [ -f file2 ]; then

  cat file2 > file1
  sed -i 's#some operation' file1
  cat file3 >> file1

  exit 0

  elif [ ! -f file2 ]; then

  cat file1 > file2
  sed -i 's#some operation' file1
  cat file3 >> file1

  exit 0

  else

  echo "something"
  exit 1

  fi
```

Any ideas how to do it simpler ?
Without using that much cat and files ?

Thanks !

Comment: `sed -i 's# some operation' file1 ;  cat file2 >> file1` ?

Comment: What is your `echo -n > file1` doing here? It seems superfluous, but I'm guessing it's one of those strange tricks that I haven't caught yet.

Comment: True, sorry my idiocy... I just rethinked it and this is what I need to really achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your original question:

```
cat file1 > file1.bak
sed -i 's# some operation' file1.bak
cat file2 >> file1.bak
echo -n > file1
cat file1.bak > file1
rm -f file1.bak
```

the simpler answer is (as I said in the comments):

```
sed -i 's# some operation' file1
cat file2 >> file1
```

For the edited question - bit more explanation.

In your condition:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f file2 ]; then
...
elif [ ! -f file2 ]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

The `else` will never happenes. *If the `file1` exists and is a regular file.* the `if-then` will run, and if you negate the above will run the `elif-then`. E.g. you can simplify it to

```
if [ -f file2 ]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

Now to the actions:

The:

```
cat file2 > file1
sed -i 's#some operation' file1
cat file3 >> file1
```

is the same as:

```
sed 's#some operation' <file2 >file1
cat file3 >> file1
```

and the:

```
cat file1 > file2
sed -i 's#some operation' file1
cat file3 >> file1
```

is OK - you creating a backup (copy) of the `file1` to `file2`. This could be written also as `cp file1 file2`.

Comparing the two sections, you in both doing the same thing:

```
cat file3 >> file1
```

so, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) - and do this after the `if`, because it is common for both parts.

So, we get:

```
if [ -f file2 ]; then
    sed 's#some operation' <file2 >file1
else
    cp file1 file2  #make the copy
    sed -i 's#some operation' file1
fi
cat file3 >> file1
```

Also, the

```
sed 's#some operation' <file2 >file1
#and
sed -i 's#some operation' file1
```

are very similar - e.g. the result of the `sed` operations always going into the `file1`. Moreover, in the `else` you copying the `file1` to `file2` so the

```
cat file1 > file2
sed -i 's#some operation' file1
```

could be written also as

```
cp file1 file2
sed 's#some operation' <file2 >file1
```

and we got the indentical `sed` command for both cases, so - DRY again.

```
if [ -f file2 ]; then
    : #do nothing here...
else
    cp file1 file2  #make the copy
fi
sed 's#some operation' <file2 >file1
cat file3 >> file1
```

But the `do nothing` part is unnecessary, so we got:

```
if [ ! -f file2 ]; then
    cp file1 file2  #make the copy
fi
sed 's#some operation' <file2 >file1
cat file3 >> file1
```

this could be shortened using `[[ condition ]] && ...` but it is not needed for now. :)

Also it could be **very** helpful name your files more precisely. The `file1` and so on - telling you nothing about the content.

Comment: I have another question which needs your kind of explanation if you would mind and have time: https://serverfault.com/questions/888526/remoteipinternalproxy-remoteiptrustedproxy

Comment: @DaWe4444 - enjoy, also you could read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's# some operation' file1
cat file2 >> file1
```

Comment: True, sorry my idiocy... I just rethinked it and this is what I need to really achieve.